# How to use jQuery .val() in a salesforce aura lightning component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

I'm attempting to to use jQuery `.val()` function on the following page to pre-fill some info:

https://tophatsupport.force.com/s/contactsupport

I'm using something along the lines of:

```
$("input[placeholder='Top Hat Username *']").val("This is a test");
```

This works and fills the field, but when I attempt to submit the form, it flags the field as invalid, almost as if there is nothing filled in there yet.

I'm wondering if anyone here knows how to fill these fields using JS or jQuery and for them to be valid fields upon submission of the form.

I appreciate your help interwebs!

Answer (score 0):

The url you have given has some kind of javascript on page which checks the url every 500 ms and updates the values of the username and email field with the values in the url query string. If the url does not have any query string then the blank value is being updated which is creating the problem.
If this is your page then the javascript has to be modified to not update the field if the query string is not present.
If you provide the query string then the email and username is being populated like providing window.location.search = "username=This is a test&email=test@test.com".

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery snippet is correct and works as expected. It is just that you have setted up `setInterval` that constantly overrides your input fields:

```
queryOutput = setInterval(function(){ 
    if($(".queryOutput").parent()){
        console.log("Found queryOutput, appending test text.");
        $(".queryOutput").html("Username: " + getQueryVariable("username") + "<br>" + "First Name: " + getQueryVariable("firstname") + "<br> Last Name: " + getQueryVariable("lastname"));
        if($("input[placeholder='Top Hat Username *']")){

            // HERE: getQueryVariable("username") returns undefined.
            $("input[placeholder='Top Hat Username *']").val(getQueryVariable("username"));
            $("input[placeholder='Email *']").val(getQueryVariable("email"));

        }
        if($(".queryOutput").html() != "Query output here"){
            //clearInterval(queryOutput);   
        }
    }
 }, 500);
```

Comment: Uzbekjon, thanks for your response! The issue is that if you run clearInterval(queryOutput); in your console then try using the .val() function an error will still be returned. Alternatively, if you use the URL: 

https://tophatsupport.force.com/s/contactsupport?username=test123&email=test@gmail.com

Then theoretically it should be able to accept this pre-fill data into the form, but it does not and think that it has not been filled in. I have it update every 500 ms because some back end script auto clears the values on submit. This is a really interesting puzzle that I can't seem to crack